# SharedPreferences.открытие Activity после Login и Logout

Tags: java, android

Есть MainActivity с логин формой,  кнопка с таким кодом и переходом в следующее окно.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
ed.putString("SAVED_TOKEN", token);
ed.putBoolean("IS_AUTHORIZED", true);
ed.apply();
```

И идет переход в User_Main
в манифесте указал тут

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

и в `User_Main`есть кнопка с логаутом с возвратом в предыдущее, MainActivity

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences.edit();
 ed.putBoolean("IS_AUTHORIZED", false);
 ed.apply();
 Intent intent_logout=new Intent(User_Main.this,MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent_logout);
```

в OnCreate в MainActivity идет проверка на `"IS_AUTHORIZED"`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean isAuthodized = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("IS_AUTHORIZED", false);
 if (isAuthodized){
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,User_Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

При логауте почему то остаюсь на месте, и окна не меняются и проблема в OnCreate блоке видимо. А задача простая, если юзер залогинился то после сворачивания и открытия- открывается `User_Main`, если разлогинился то `MainActivity`

Делаю это в первый раз, не могу догнать как правильно реализовать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getPreferences()` создает файл настроек, доступный только в пределах одной активити. То есть, в каждой активити у вас самостятельный файл с собственными значениями, соответственно то, что вы записываете в первой активити, никак не попадает во вторую. Для доступа к значениям настроек в пределах всего приложения, а не одной активити, используйте `getSharedPreferences()`.

[Подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) о разнице файлов настроек.